# Main Kernel can no longer be loaded

Tags: boot, kernel

After a reboot my main Kernel can no longer be loaded. It is stuck at "Loading Linux <kernelversion>-generic". I can boot with one of my backup kernels. Recently I executed

```
sudo apt-get purge $(for tag in "linux-image" "linux-headers"; do dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' "$tag-[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" | sort -V | awk 'index($0,c){exit} //' c=$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2); done)
```

to free up space in the boot partition. I did that in the past and it caused no problems. I do not know if I rebooted between the last time I executed that command and if it might be related to my kernel problem.

What should I do to solve this? What information or logs do you need?

Comment: One way would be to just install new kernel with all needed files from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.6/ f.ex. "Generic", after that run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Or just `sudo apt install linux-image-generic` to get the latest official kernel installed

Comment: @Serafim Is that a low risk operation or risky like for example a dist-upgrade?

Comment: It is a low risk operation. If it says that the latest kernel is already installed then redo the same command with `--reinstall`option. It will just make sure that the latest official kernel is installed.

Comment: And also, I assume that you can only boot from one of your backup kernels, and in that case select the oldest backup kernel to boot from. You will probably not be able to reinstall the kernel you boot from. I would not recommend an install from the mainline ppa.